# Affinity designer - reveal layer in layers on element click

Tags: affinity-designer

I got two probably primitive questions

1) when you `cmd + click` on layer in your canvas, it gets selected. But how do you achieve the same effect as in Photoshop to simultaneously get the layer revealed in layers panel so you can directly operate with it?

2) is there faster way to expand/collapse a group rather than clicking small arrow in the layers panel?

Answer (score 1):

On the canvas, just right click on a selected layer and choose "Find in layers panel".

Answer (score 1):

1) You can go to Preferences, then: User Interface -> check: Show Selection in Layers Panel

2) Still not available

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!